# Executing a Postman collection using Java

Tags: java, cucumber, postman, gherkin, postman-collection

In Postman, using Rest, I created a collection of requests that need to be executed.  I was hoping to link Gherkin acceptance Criteria with the cucumber shell to execute the Postman collection.

Is there a way for me, in the cucumber shell, to execute the collection using Java?

Gherkin, Cucumber and Java are all new to me so I apologize if I'm not exactly clear.

thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Can you execute the collection of requests using Java? That is, leaving the Cucumber and Gherkin out of the equation? If you can, then you can do it using Cucumber as well.

The execution of steps defined in Gherkin using Cucumber is just a way of executing selected Java methods matching the steps you define in Gherkin.

This is obviously under the condition that you choose to run Cucumber for Java.

To get started and have something to build from, clone and run the getting started project offered by the Cucumber team, https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton